# Fixing number of digits after comma

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to fix the number of digits after the comma (or decimal point) for a decimal result of a Cypher query:

```
match(n)
.
.
.
return(X)
```

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to round to a specific decimal precision so it you have to multiply to gross it up, round it and divide by the same number you multiplied by again to get back to the precision you desire.

Consider the following example to round to the nearest thousandth.

```
with 1.23456789 as dec_raw
return round(dec_num * 1000) / 1000 as dec_precision
```

Comment: Thank you for this issue. its useful!!